# Trying to build Telegram (Desktop) from source

Tags: c++, qt, build-process, telegram

I'm trying to built the Telegram Desktop client from source using the [instructions on Github](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/master/QTCREATOR.md). I'm up to this point:

> Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits tab > Desktop (default) > change
>   Qt version to Qt 5.4.0 (Qt-5.4.0) > Apply Open MetaStyle.pro,
>   configure project with paths
>   /home/user/TBuild/tdesktop/Linux/DebugIntermediateStyle and
>   /home/user/TBuild/tdesktop/Linux/ReleaseIntermediateStyle and build
>   for Debug

I can open MetaStyle.pro, but I don't know what the instructions mean by "configure project with paths...".

Does it mean I have to add those directories to the INCLUDEPATH? The OBJECTS_DIR?

Answer (score 1):

When you open a project file with Qt Creator, it first prompts you to configure the project. If it doesn't, select the "Projects" button at the left side of QtCreator and click the "Build & Run" tab.

Under the Build Settings header, choose which build configuration you want to change ("Edit build configuration: " Debug/Release).

For the Debug configuration, set the debug "Build Directory" as

```
/home/user/TBuild/tdesktop/Linux/DebugIntermediateStyle
```

If the field is grayed out, check the "Shadow Build" box.
For the Release configuration, set the release directory as

```
/home/user/TBuild/tdesktop/Linux/ReleaseIntermediateStyle
```

Comment: When I click the "Projects" button in the left hand side, no "Configure Project" tab is displayed.

Comment: Your answer implied that you're using Linux. Are you using Windows perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm using Linux in my question. I'm also using Qt Creator 5.5.

Comment: Changed answer for different QtCreator, please try this.